# Find a vector function for the curve of intersection of $x^2 +y^2 = 9$ and $y+z=2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Find a vector function for the curve of intersection of $x^2 +y^2 = 9$ and $y+z=2$

I'm not sure how to solve this problem.  I know whenever we want to find an intersection we typically set the two functions equal to each other and solve them.  I'm confused with this particular problem, though.

I tried to using trig identities to solve the problem but I cannot get the correct solution provided in the book.

$cos^2(\theta) + sin^2(\theta)=9$

$cos(\theta) + sin(\theta)= 3$

Any suggestions as to how to get started with this one?  Am I on the right path?

Solution:

$⟨3cos(t),3sin(t),2−3sin(t)⟩$

Comment: It's always true that $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$. On the other hand, if we multiply both sides of this equation by $9$...

Comment: @Travis oh, I think this is what I was missing?!  I was just plugging the trig identity in without compensating for the 9.  So you're saying it should be $9cos^2(t)+9sin^2(t)=9$?

Comment: Yes, so, that means we can parameterize the circle in the plane by $x = 3 \cos t$, $y = 3 \sin t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

1. The projection of the curve to the $xy$-plane also has equation $$x^2 + y^2 = 9.$$ Can you parameterize this curve?
2. With this in hand, if you know the projection $(x, y)$ of the point $(x, y, z)$ on the intersection of the two surfaces, can you recover $z$?

> **Additional hint** 3. What is $z$ as a function of the parameter you chose?

Comment: Thanks for the hint!  I think I got it.  I'll post up what I have shortly

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$x=3\cos t \quad and \quad y=3\sin t \Rightarrow x^2+y^2=9$$
and:
$$
x^2+y^2=9 \Rightarrow \qquad \exists t \in \mathbb{R} \quad such \, that \quad x=3\cos t \quad and \quad y=3\sin t 
$$
and, from the second equation, you have $z=2-y$.

Comment: How is it that $x=3cos t$ when I'm getting $x=3-y$?

Comment: Where comes from $x=3-y$?

Answer (score 0):

using $x=r cos\theta, y=r sin\theta, z=z,$

you get $(r cos\theta)^2+ (r sin\theta)^2=9$ and $r sin\theta +z =2$

so $r^2=9$ and $r=3$

thus $x=3 cos\theta, y=3 sin\theta, z=2-3sin\theta,$